# JformDesigner- Eclipse Main won't run

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jform-designer

So I did go through and saw a few questions similar to mine but the fixes that worked for them still wouldn't get the window to display for me. I am attempting to create a login screen, This is the generated code and I copied over the public static main from previous questions but it still only displays a window of the smallest size with nothing in it:

```
package surveyducky;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.*;

public class LoginForm extends JFrame{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public LoginForm() {
        initComponents();
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                 LoginForm GUI = new LoginForm();
                 GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                 GUI.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    private void submitActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO add your code here
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        // JFormDesigner - Component initialization - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
        // Generated using JFormDesigner Evaluation license - Tamara Turton
        DefaultComponentFactory compFactory = DefaultComponentFactory.getInstance();
        LoginJ = new JPanel();
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        titel = compFactory.createTitle("Welcome to Survey Ducky!");
        userlabel = new JLabel();
        email = new JTextField();
        passlabel = new JLabel();
        password = new JPasswordField();
        vSpacer1 = new JPanel(null);
        submit = new JButton();
        forgotpass = new JButton();
        createacc = new JButton();

        //======== LoginJ ========
        {   
            // JFormDesigner evaluation mark
            LoginJ.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder(
                new javax.swing.border.TitledBorder(new javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0),
                    "JFormDesigner Evaluation", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER,
                    javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.BOTTOM, new java.awt.Font("Dialog", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 12),
                    java.awt.Color.red), LoginJ.getBorder())); LoginJ.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener(){public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent e){if("border".equals(e.getPropertyName()))throw new RuntimeException();}});

            LoginJ.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            ((GridBagLayout)LoginJ.getLayout()).columnWidths = new int[] {0, 163};
            ((GridBagLayout)LoginJ.getLayout()).rowHeights = new int[] {50, 43, 27, 47, 25, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0};
            ((GridBagLayout)LoginJ.getLayout()).rowWeights = new double[] {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0E-4};

            //======== panel1 ========
            {
                panel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                ((GridBagLayout)panel1.getLayout()).columnWidths = new int[] {353};
                ((GridBagLayout)panel1.getLayout()).rowHeights = new int[] {0, 0, 0};
                ((GridBagLayout)panel1.getLayout()).rowWeights = new double[] {0.0, 0.0, 1.0E-4};

                //---- titel ----
                titel.setFont(new Font("Brush Script MT", Font.BOLD, 30));
                panel1.add(titel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 2, 0.0, 0.0,
                    GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                    new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            }
            LoginJ.add(panel1, new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0), 0, 0));

            //---- userlabel ----
            userlabel.setText("Username:");
            userlabel.setLabelFor(email);
            LoginJ.add(userlabel, new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0), 0, 0));
            LoginJ.add(email, new GridBagConstraints(1, 2, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0), 0, 0));

            //---- passlabel ----
            passlabel.setText("Password:");
            passlabel.setLabelFor(password);
            LoginJ.add(passlabel, new GridBagConstraints(1, 3, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0), 0, 0));
            LoginJ.add(password, new GridBagConstraints(1, 4, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0), 0, 0));
            LoginJ.add(vSpacer1, new GridBagConstraints(0, 5, 1, 2, 0.0, 0.0,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5), 0, 0));

            //---- submit ----
            submit.setText("Submit");
            submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    submitActionPerformed(e);
                    submitActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
            LoginJ.add(submit, new GridBagConstraints(1, 6, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0), 0, 0));

            //---- forgotpass ----
            forgotpass.setText("Forgot Password?");
            LoginJ.add(forgotpass, new GridBagConstraints(1, 7, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0), 0, 0));

            //---- createacc ----
            createacc.setText("Create Account");
            LoginJ.add(createacc, new GridBagConstraints(1, 8, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
        }
        // JFormDesigner - End of component initialization  //GEN-END:initComponents
    }

    // JFormDesigner - Variables declaration - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:variables
    // Generated using JFormDesigner Evaluation license - Tamara Turton
    private JPanel LoginJ;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JLabel titel;
    private JLabel userlabel;
    private JTextField email;
    private JLabel passlabel;
    private JPasswordField password;
    private JPanel vSpacer1;
    private JButton submit;
    private JButton forgotpass;
    private JButton createacc;
    // JFormDesigner - End of variables declaration  //GEN-END:variables
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating and customizing a content panel - `LoginJ`, but not assigning it to the frame. At the end of `initComponents` method, you should do:

```
this.setContentPane(this.LoginJ);
```

You will see your form elements, and then you can further customize, e.g. enlarge and center the dialog.